# php error on localhost: Access forbidden! error 403

Tags: php, xampp

I am following [this](http://www.hardcoder.com/scripting/php/guestbook/index.php) php tutorial on windows7 using XAMPP.
It's a guest book tutorial that saves user entries into mysql & displays entries from db.
when I enter data into form & submit it, browser shows this error msg

**Access forbidden!**
*You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.* 
**Error 403**
localhost
*Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7*

**UPDATED**

**guestbok.php**

> Connect to DB Code

```
<?php
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbDatabase = "myDB";

// Connect to DB

$li = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'myDB') or 
      die("Could not connect". mysqli_connect_error());
//mysql_select_db($dbDatabase, $li) or 
      die ("could not select DB". mysql_error());
?>
```

> Variables initialisation

```
<?php
// initiate some vars

$gb_str = "";   
// $gb_str is the string we'll append entries to
$pgeTitle = "View and Sign Guestbook";
```

> Post request handling

```
// If form is submitted, then insert into DB
if (!empty($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST["frmName"];
    $email = $_POST["frmEmail"];
    $comment = $_POST["frmComment"];
    $date = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

    $gb_query =     "insert into guestbook
            values(0, '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$date')";
    // Performs the $sql query on the server to insert the values
    if ($li->query($gb_query) === TRUE) {
        echo 'users entry saved successfully';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error: '. $li->error;
    }
    /*
    $sql = mysql_query($gb_query);
    $res = mysql_affected_rows($sql);

    // See if insert was successful or not
    if($res > 0) {
        $ret_str="Your guestbook entry was successfully added.";
    } else {
        $ret_str = "Your guestbook entry was NOT successfully added.";
    }

    // Append success/failure message
    $gb_str .= "<span class=\"ret\">$ret_str</span><BR>";
    */
}
?>
```

> GuestBook list

```
<?php

$get_query = "select gbName, gbEmail, gbComment, 
              DATE_FORMAT(gbDateAdded, '%m-%d-%y %H:%i') gbDateAdded
              from guestbook";

$result = $li->query($get_query);
$gb_str .= "<hr size=\"1\">";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row from $result
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $row["gbName"];
    $email = $row["gbEmail"];
    $comment = $row["gbComment"];
    $date = $row["gbDateAdded"];

    if(!empty($name)) {
        // If name exists and email exists, link name to email
        if(!empty($email)) {
            $name="by <a href=\"mailto:$email\">$name</a>";
        }
    // If name does exist and email exists, link email to email     
    } else if (!empty($email)) {
        $name = "by <a href=\"mailto:$email\">$email</a>";
    } else {
        $name = "";
    }

    // Append to string we'll print later on
    $gb_str .= "<br>$comment<p class=\"small\">
                posted on $date $name<hr size=\"1\">";
}}

?>
```

> The HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Guestbook</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
<!--

/* This function is pulled from a generic validation file from
some other site (probably developer.netscape.com) and strips out
characters you don't want */

function stripCharsInBag (s, bag) {
    var i;
    var returnString = "";

    // Search through string's characters one by one.
    // If character is not in bag, append to returnString.

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {   
        // Check that current character isn't whitespace.
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (bag.indexOf(c) == -1) returnString += c;
    }
    return returnString;
}

// This function just makes sure the comment field is not empty

function valForm(frm) {
    badChars = "<[]>{}";
    if(frm.frmComment.value == "") {
        alert("Please fill in your comments for the guestbook.");
        return false;
    } else {
        frm.frmComment.value = stripCharsInBag(frm.frmComment.value, badChars);
        // These values may be empty, but strip chars in case they're not
        frm.frmName.value = stripCharsInBag(frm.frmName.value, badChars);
        frm.frmEmail.value = stripCharsInBag(frm.frmEmail.value, badChars);
        return true;
    }
}

-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<?php echo $gb_str; ?>

<form name="gb" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdhead" valign="top" align="right">Name</td>
    <td valign="top">
      <input type="text" name="frmName" value="" size="30" 
             maxlength="50">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdhead" valign="top" align="right">Email</td>
    <td valign="top">
      <input type="text" name="frmEmail" value="" size="30" 
             maxlength="100">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdhead" valign="top" align="right">Comment</td>
    <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="frmComment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" 
               onClick="return valForm(document.gb)">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>

<?php
// Close MySQL Connection
$li->close();
?>
```

Comment: 1. DO NOT USE the `mysql_xxx()` functions. They are considered **obsolete and insecure**. The PHP manual strongly recommends switching to either the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Comment: 2. DO NOT USE the "short style PHP tags": ie `<?`. You should always use the longer style PHP tags: `<?php`. The short version is considered obsolete and is not supported by some PHP installations. It may be deprecated and/or removed from PHP entirely in the future.

Comment: 3. DO NOT USE `$HTTP_POST_VARS`. This is obsolete in PHP, and has been for a long time. You should use `$_POST` instead.

Comment: 4. Your are not escaping the input data in your SQL query. This leaves you wide open to a SQL injection hack. This is incredibly insecure.

Comment: Overall, I strongly recommend stopping with that tutorial, and go find a more up-to-date tutorial that doesn't teach bad practice. I'd suggest some of the articles here: http://phpmaster.com/

Comment: OK, actually I was looking for a simple tutorial that has a little project fully done. Most I find were using lot of other stuff inc ajax etc. I wanting a kind of pure php-mysql project on top of that I can then also add & practice other php things I learned. Can you plz provide a link for such good project.

Comment: There are some more issues with this code. that are where in some statments, double quot is escaped by back slash like here:
 $gb_str .= "<span class=\"ret\">$ret_str</span><BR>";
the browser is having issues with it & showing source code in window. I changed all escaped d-quotes with single quote like 
 $gb_str .= "<span class=\'ret\'>$ret_str</span><BR>";
Does it have some issues ??

Comment: re the escaped quotes in the html code: the way you have it, it doesn't need to be escaped, but the topic would probably be better as a whole separate question rather than trying to cram an answer into the comments here. Re a tutorial: try this one: http://phpmaster.com/building-your-own-url-shortener/ (it's not a guestbook, but it is a small complete self-contained tutorial that uses  modern best practice techniques to produce a complete working system from start to finish)

Comment: OK, I used MySqli api now but it is raising same error. Other escaping things I recover.

Comment: @SDC: phpmaster.com/building-your-own-url-shortener is very nice link & whole site is very nice source for learning php. But it has no front end so that I could see how things are working.

Answer (score 1):

2nd questions answer, you have not assigned query result to variable and `mysql_affected_rows` is also empty.

```
$gb_query =     "insert into guestbook
        values(0, '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$date')";

$sql = mysql_query($gb_query);
$res = mysql_affected_rows($sql);
```

Comment: I made these changes but still there are no results displayed

Comment: I made a new file from same to implement suggestions from this post & entries are displayed now, but I cannot insert values still. Same error

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the error is caused by the Xampp configuration blocking the directory. If you are on a development machine and don't care about security, look for a file called httpd.conf in the apache/conf dir under xampp.

You will find a directive in there similar to this

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from none
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Replace it with this

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
</Directory>
```

That makes every file on your root drive accessible to the webserver, which on a development machine is fine (although some are bound to argue the point), but in production not a good idea at all.